# for loop in API call returns same result in each loop

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, for-loop, limesurvey

I have written a loop to retrieve data from an API (Limesurvey) based on a list of ids and fill a row of a dataframe with the result of each loop.

I have a list with ids like this:

```
 # list of ids

 ids = ['1','427',... ,'847']
```

My code to query the API based on each item of the list looks as follows:

```
method = "get_participant_properties"
params = OrderedDict([
            ("sSessionKey", api.session_key),
            ("iSurveyID", 12345),
            ("aTokenQueryProperties", t), 
])

# loop through API query with the 'aTokenQueryProperties' stored in the list 'tids'.

attributes = []

for t in ids:
    attributes.append(api.query(method=method, params=params))

pd.DataFrame(attributes)
```

Unfortunately, the result is a dataframe with 158 rows, and each row is the same, i.e. the query result of the last id in my list (847).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing in the `t` from the loop. The `t` in the `params` definition is unrelated; if I were to run your code now I'd get a `NameError` exception because `t` hasn't been set at that point. The `t` expression in the `params` mapping is *not live*, it is not updated each loop iteration.

Set the `'aTokenQueryProperties'` key *in the loop*:

```
method = "get_participant_properties"
params = OrderedDict([
            ("sSessionKey", api.session_key),
            ("iSurveyID", 12345),
            ("aTokenQueryProperties", None), 
])

attributes = []

for t in ids:
    params["aTokenQueryProperties"] = t
    attributes.append(api.query(method=method, params=params))
```

Setting `"aTokenQueryProperties"` to `None` in the `params` `OrderedDict` object at the start is optional; you'd only need to do this if reserving its exact location in the `params` order is important and even then, because in your example it is the *last* element in the mapping, you'd end up with the same output anyway.